# Error while build my react app (UglifyJs)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

When i run build of my react app i got: `ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: name` i found this https://github.com/joeeames/WebpackFundamentalsCourse/issues/3
they suggest use babel-reset-es2015 but i need babel-preset-react.
My webpack config:

```js
const path = require('path')

const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")

const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: "style.css",
    disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
});

const config = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",

  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname + "/dist")
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: {presets:['react']}
      },

      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        enforce: 'pre',

        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        options: {
          emitWarning: true,
        }
      },

      { test: /\.html$/,
        use:[{
          loader: 'html-loader',
          options: {
            minimize:true
          }
        }]
      },

      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: extractSass.extract({
          use: [{
              loader: "css-loader"
          }, {
              loader: "sass-loader"
          }],
          fallback: "style-loader"
        })
      }
  ]},

  plugins: [
    extractSass
  ],

  node:{
    fs: "empty"
  }
}

module.exports = config
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have both, they are not mutually exclusive. Also `query` has been replaced with `options` in webpack 2, just as you're using it in your other loaders already. `query` still exists for compatibility reasons, but you should just use `options`.

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: "babel-loader",
  options: {
    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks, i was thinking this react preset contain es2015 but now it's working ;)